# How to convert an integer value to time (HH:MM:SS) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of integer value which can be either a single digit to 6 digit number. Now I want to convert this set of values to time representing the `HH:MM:SS` format. I thought of converting first to varchar then to time but it didn't work out. Can anyone help me out with the problem?

Comment: What would a single digit mean? Please give a [mcve] containing sample data and expected results (please cover all edge cases). Have you looked at the `TIMEFROMPARTS` function?

Comment: So the numbers basically represents time but not in the standard format that is used. e.g. 606 would represent 00:06:06. Similarly 123456 would represent the time 12:34:56. A single digit can be 6 which would mean 00:00:06.
And I haven't used `TIMEFROMPARTS` functions

Comment: Hint: `123456 / 10000 = 12`, `(123456 / 100) % 100 = 34`, `123456 % 100 = 56`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TIMEFROMPARTS`

```sql
SELECT
  TIMEFROMPARTS(
    YourColumn / 10000,
    YourColumn / 100 % 100,
    YourColumn % 100
  )
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens to be what run times look like in msdb..sysjobschedules, which I've addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73515393/1800725). Assuming "val" is your integer, try:

```
select dateadd(s, val - ((val / 100) * 40) - ((val / 10000) * 2400), 0/*or some date*/)
```

(subtracting out 40 seconds per minute and 40*100 + 2400 seconds per hour to get the actual number of seconds, then adding that many seconds to a date.)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
date (dateadd(second,value,'19700101'))
```

Comment: A suggestion to try something is not an answer.

Comment: @GertArnold Of course it is; what else would an answer be?  It's something to try to solve the problem.  I'm not sure this particular answer actually addresses the correct problem, which is a separate issue, but I'm a little unclear on the question itself to be honest (specifically, how the number is supposed to be converted to HH:MM:SS) (edit: actually this is addressed in a comment, which confirms this answer is incorrect).

Comment: @RyanM I would never post such a one-liner as an answer. It should at least explain why it (probably) answers the question and under which assumptions (since, yes, the question is not clear). What I don't like about "try this" answers is that they hardly ever get due confirmation that they were actually helpful. It's frustrating for later readers.